# my app can not connect to kafka cluster on built by docker-compose

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose

I am trying to connect my spring boot app to kafka cluster on docker-compose.yml, but I get conection error.
I tried to ping `kafka-1` service onto my app's container and it DOES pinged.

this is my entire docker compose code:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  zookeeper:
    container_name: zookeeper
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.5.0
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    networks:
      - ams_net
  kafka-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.5.0
    container_name: kafka-1
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "19092:19092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka-1:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:19092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    networks:
      - ams_net
  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.5.0
    container_name: schema-registry
    hostname: schema-registry
    depends_on:
     - kafka-1
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_CONNECTION_URL: 'zookeeper:2181'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://schema-registry:8081
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka-1:9092,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL://localhost:19092
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_DEBUG: 'true'
    networks:
      - ams_net
  my-app:
    container_name: my-app
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - kafka-1
    environment:
      - SERVER_PORT=8080
      - BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka1:9092
      - SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL=http://schema-registry:8081
      - AVRO_SUBJECT_VERSION=latest
      - CACHE_MAX_SIZE_BUFFERING=0
    ports:
      - "9898:8080"
    networks:
      - ams_net

networks:
  ams_net:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Schema Registry only needs Kafka-1, what are Kafka2, 3?

Comment: kafka-2 and kafka-3 are just additional brokers for cluster.

Comment: Change BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS to 'kafka-1:9092'

Comment: Unrelated, but localhost:19092 isn't a valid broker for the registry (it cannot connect to itself as a Kafka store)

Answer (score 0):

1. Ping doesn't verify `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS` are set correctly
2. `depends_on` doesn't wait for containers to become healthy.

   If you're trying to immediately start a Kafka client in your code, you need to sleep that thread for at least 5-10 seconds for the Kafka process to actually start, or catch your connection exceptions and retry
3. Your `BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS` variable is set to `kafka1`. But the container name is actually `kafka-1`. Also, Spring boot auto-configuration from environment variables would use `SPRING_KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS`, and otherwise default to connect to `localhost:9092`

Comment: Here is my application.properties 
`spring.application.name=accident-data-stream
server.port=${SERVER_PORT:8080}

spring.kafka.streams.application-id=${spring.application.name}
spring.kafka.streams.bootstrap-servers=${BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS}
spring.kafka.streams.cache-max-size-buffering=${CACHE_MAX_SIZE_BUFFERING}
spring.kafka.streams.state-dir=${STATE_DIRECTORY}

specific.avro.reader.value.subject.version=${AVRO_SUBJECT_VERSION}
spring.kafka.properties.schema.registry.url=${SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL}`

Comment: Okay. You can edit your question to include that